How to get credentialsId from descriptor at the job level in Jenkins via the groovy console?
My goal is to update the credentials in the Bitbucket Notifier (=plugin) post-build action for a number of builds. The builds are using the old Freestyle project style (unfortunately).
To get started I'm just trying to list them. This code works but the pub.descriptor.getCredentialsId() part return the globally defined credentialId and not the one at the job level. What am I missing?
jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(hudson.model.FreeStyleProject.class).findAll{ it.getFullDisplayName().contains("BB")}.each{ job ->
  job.getPublishersList().findAll{it.descriptor.displayName == "Notify Bitbucket Instance"}.each{ pub -> 
    println (job.fullDisplayName + " - " + pub.descriptor.getCredentialsId())
  }
}
// https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/stashNotifier/org/jenkinsci/plugins/stashNotifier/StashNotifier.html
// https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Descriptor.html

